# Запрос к АПИ при отсутствии некоторых данных

Tags: api

Есть запрос к АПИ, но некоторые данные могут быть не выбраны. Допустим, не будет указана минимальная цена, а только максимальная и наоборот. Как убрать из запроса данные?

Скорее всего, через if не вариант. Пример.

```
if (valueType === 'Choose any type') {
        valueType = "";
    }
```

Тогда будет запрос, но с пустым параметром. А мне нужно именно не отправлять данные.

```
const data = new URLSearchParams();       
    data.append('minprice', minBudget)
    data.append('maxprice', maxBudget)        
    data.append('participants', participants)
    data.append('accessibility', access)
    data.append('type', valueType)
    const newData = await this.getResource(`?${data}`);
    return newData;
```

Comment: по if который определяет наличие данных не делайте append если данных нет

Comment: а как это записать? Подскажите?

Comment: if(condition){ data.append... }

Comment: Это я поняла. Но мне нужно именно пропустить append, если данных нет.